# Select values that are duplicated after removing special characters in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My goal is to search for SKU values that are duplicated if we exclude special characters and get ids of those records.

```
INSERT INTO 
    sneakers (sneaker_id, sku)
VALUES
    (1, '111-111'),
    (2, '111/111'),
    (3, '222-222'),
    (4, '333:333'),
    (5, '333-333');
```

In this example I want to get sneaker_id 1,2,4,5 because SKUs for those records are duplicated apart from the special character.
Here's the approach that I came up with:

```
SELECT sneaker_id, sku
FROM sneakers
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(sku, '[\]\\[!@#$%.&*`~^_{}:;<>/\\|()-]+', ' ') IN (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(sku, '[\]\\[!@#$%.&*`~^_{}:;<>/\\|()-]+', ' ')
FROM sneakers
GROUP BY REGEXP_REPLACE(sku, '[\]\\[!@#$%.&*`~^_{}:;<>/\\|()-]+', ' ')
HAVING COUNT(REGEXP_REPLACE(sku, '[\]\\[!@#$%.&*`~^_{}:;<>/\\|()-]+', ' ')) >1);
```

It works when testing it on example table, however running this query on my main table (235k records) takes way too long (up to 10 mins).
How to achieve the same result optimizing performance?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you maintain a second column called "clean_sku" or equivalent.

You can then use PG triggers to keep it in sync with the source data.

For example

```
alter table sneakers add clean_sku varchar(64); -- check size, no schema in original question
```

Then create a function to maintain it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sneaker_update()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    new.clean_sku := REGEXP_REPLACE(new.sku, '[\]\\[!@#$%.&*`~^_{}:;<>/\\|()-]+', ' ');
    RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Once you have the function, you can create insert and update triggers to maintain it:

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER sneakerinsert
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON sneakers
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE sneaker_update();

CREATE or replace TRIGGER sneakerupdate
  before update of sku
  ON sneakers
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE sneaker_update();
```

Essentially, this conversion of the initial data to a representation that will perform for querying only needs to be repeated whenever the source data is changed.

In database programming this pattern appears again and again, we are going to put the data in a format that supports the performance needs of our application, and we are going to use the "constraining" mechanisms in the DB engine to insure our data integrity.   And then we will write some documentation explaining why we did it :)

Update from comments:   as @Belayer indicated in the comments this pattern has now been encapsulated in Postgres:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

which could be the preferred approach if your code will always be deployed to a version that supports it.   I will leave my version up since this is the canonical approach and it is good to learn, since it works in RDBMS that supports insert or update triggers.

From there its a simple as

```
SELECT  sneaker_id
FROM    sneakers
WHERE   clean_sku IN
(
    SELECT  clean_sku
    FROM    sneakers
    GROUP   BY clean_sku
    HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  sneaker_id,
  sku,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(sku,'[\]\\[!@#$%.&*`~^_{}:;<>/\\|()-]+', ' '),
  x.count
FROM sneakers
LEFT JOIN (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(sku,'[\]\\[!@#$%.&*`~^_{}:;<>/\\|()-]+', ' ') skux, count(*) 
         from sneakers 
         group by REGEXP_REPLACE(sku,'[\]\\[!@#$%.&*`~^_{}:;<>/\\|()-]+', ' ')) x ON 
              x.skux = REGEXP_REPLACE(sku,'[\]\\[!@#$%.&*`~^_{}:;<>/\\|()-]+', ' ')
WHERE x.count > 1
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/RJQ9sCKo)

Just count how many time the sku is in the set after replacement.

Comment: Works great, 15s! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly efficient

```sql
select * 
from (
  select 
    x.*,
    count(*) over (partition by skux) cnt
  from (
    SELECT
      sneaker_id,
      sku,
      REGEXP_REPLACE(sku,'[\]\\[!@#$%.&*`~^_{}:;<>/\\|()-]+', ' ') skux
    from sneakers 
  ) x
) x
where cnt > 1
```

It accesses the table only once, and also makes the conversion only once.

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wylNnJxp)

If this still doesn't meet your performance needs you might create a [functional index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/indexes-functional.html) of the normalized sku.

Or keep it as a normal column in the table

Answer (score 0):

I would second the suggestion by @BretWeinraub that you create an additional column. However, if you have v12 or greater, instead of maintaining its value via triggers you can define it as a `generated always as ...` column. Also 2 slight changes to the regex itself:

1. Rather that a list of hard code values for special characters use
   the character class `[:alnum:]`. This way the special characters is
   determined by the *collation* that is used.
2. Extend the regex to indicate a `global` replacement. This will then
   handle a sku like `'123-456-aaa'`.

Then your desired query becomes: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ilD8mSrK))

```
select  s.sneaker_id, sku, sku_count
  from  sneakers s
  join  (select  clean_sku, count(*) sku_count
           from  sneakers
          group  by clean_sku
         having  count(*) > 1
        ) c
    on c.clean_sku = s.clean_sku
order by sku, sneaker_id;
```

Comment: applause!  "generated always as"; that made my day

Answer (score 0):

We can use Common Table Expression to solve this and improve the performance of your query.The query is as follows :

```
WITH clean_sku AS (
    SELECT
        sneaker_id,
        sku,
        REGEXP_REPLACE(sku, '[\]\\[!@#$%.&*`~^_{}:;<>/\\|()-]+', '', 'g') as clean
    FROM
        sneakers
)

SELECT
    sneaker_id,
    sku
FROM
    clean_sku
WHERE
    clean IN (
        SELECT
            clean
        FROM
            clean_sku
        GROUP BY
            clean
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
    );
```

This query looks for duplicate SKUs across all sneakers.
The WITH clean_sku AS ( ... ) creates a temporary table called clean_sku that contains the sneaker_id, sku, and a cleaned version of the sku (with all special characters removed).

Then the query selects all the sneaker_ids and skus from the clean_sku table where the cleaned sku is found more than once in the table .

Answer (score 0):

I would second the suggestion by @BretWeinraub that you create an additional column. However, if you have v12 or greater, instead of maintaining its value via triggers you can define it as a `generated always as ...` column. Also 2 slight changes to the regex itself:

1. Rather that a list of hard code values for special characters use
   the character class `[:alnum:]`. This way the list of characters is
   determined by the *collation* that is used.
2. Extend the regex to indicate a `global` replacement. This will then
   handle a sku like `'123-456-aaa'`.

Then your desired query becomes: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ilD8mSrK))

```
select  s.sneaker_id, sku, sku_count
  from  sneakers s
  join  (select  clean_sku, count(*) sku_count
           from  sneakers
          group  by clean_sku
         having  count(*) > 1
        ) c
    on c.clean_sku = s.clean_sku
order by sku, sneaker_id;
```